# What are the available option to check for the time intervals in Azure web role

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I want to hold some data in static variables and after some period of time we want to clear static object and load it from services. It's a kind of scheduling job.

I know we can go for Redis cache but we are not allowed to use it.

Any suggestions on how to clear static object after at some period of time or at particular time interval?

Comment: Are you in a distributed enviroment?

Comment: @Peter yes we are in distributed enviroment